# estimate depth with two different focal lengths

Tags: computer-vision, stereoscopy

How can we possibly estimate the depth using triangulation if left and right cameras focal length are two different value?

is there any method to do it?

and what if the positions of both cameras are not in the same height and converging?how can i measure depth with the presence of essential matrix, baseline and two different focal length?

Comment: Working with images from Curiosity? ;)

Comment: not really...i mean generally....

Comment: Yeah I'm just joking. I read once that they wanted the two cameras on the mast to be capable of having the same FOV and thus taking 3D images, but they abandoned the zoom lens as it was too expensive/complex/time consuming. So mastcam ended up with 2 different FOV.